# Boto Amazon S3 - Get bucket as iterator

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

I work with Python Boto library on my Amazon S3 server.

I want to get `bucket` object as iterator, so when I write `Bucket.next()` or something like that it will give me the next iterator.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_all_buckets()`

```
from boto.s3 import Connection
connection = Connection()
buckets = connection.get_all_buckets()  # returns a list of bucket objects
```

Now you can iterate over `buckets`.